# Yii access functions through cross controllers

Tags: php, yii

I have a 2controllers `site`  and `order`

In `order controller` i have function as

```
public function getorder() {
    .....
    .....
    $aBrought = $this->brDetails()


}

public function brDetails() {

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;            
    $criteria->condition = "sqm > 5";
    $aLevelname = $this->fetchLevelshere($criteria); //for future level

}



public function fetchLevelshere() {
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

So in the `getorder()` I called another function `brDetails`. In `brDetails` function I call `fetchLevelshere` function.

---

In my site controller i used the code as

```
public function getinformation () {
    order::getorder();
}
```

But it shows the page as null.

In my `config` i used

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.controllers.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.admin.models.*',
    'application.modules.admin.components.*',
    'application.modules.cms.components.*',
    'application.modules.cms.models.*',
    'application.extensions.yii-mail.YiiMailMessage',
    'application.modules.translate.TranslateModule',
    'ext.eoauth.*',
    'ext.eoauth.lib.*',
    'ext.lightopenid.*',
    'ext.eauth.*',
    'ext.eauth.services.*',

),
```

Why it is getting blank. Some time it shows the error as `fetchLevelshere` has Behavior haben einen Scope

What is wrong here. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: Do you render some view? And as a note: please use camelcase to name your functions (`getInformation()` not `getinformation()`)

Comment: So your controller class is `order` or `OrderController` (class that contains `getOrder()` static function)?

Comment: yes controller class is OrderController. getOrder() is the public function inside the OrderController.

Comment: @SamHanson: then you need to use `OrderController::getorder()` and not `order::getorder()`

Comment: @SamHanson, what is `$this` inside of `OrderController::getorder()` ?